# Pass method (get string[] method) to WriteAllLines method

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I've worked on this for a bit and I'm pretty stumped.  This is the syntax for WriteAllLines

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\system\path\file.txt", array[]);
```

this is working for me if the array is in this class.  I have an array in another class which I also have a getter method for.  When I try this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\selectedDays.txt", OtherClass.GetOrderDetailsArray());
```

but I get an error.  How do I pass an array from another class?  Can I use a method like this?  BTW - the method in the other class looks like this:

```
public Array GetOrderDetailsArray()
{
    return orderDetailsArray;
}
```

Comment: Make `GetOrderDetailsArray()` return a `string[]` instead of an `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.WriteAllLines` has four possible overloads:

```
WriteAllLines(String, IEnumerable<String>)
WriteAllLines(String, String[])
WriteAllLines(String, IEnumerable<String>, Encoding)
WriteAllLines(String, String[], Encoding)
```

In all four cases, the content you want to write to the file has to be either an array or a sequence of `String` values.

You are trying to pass in an object that is not a `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>`; by using `Array` as the return type, the compiler has no idea what kind of data type is in the array.

In general, it's very rare for you to want `Array` as a type by itself, because it's incredibly type-unsafe. Your method should be something like:

```
public string[] GetOrderDetailsArray()
{
    return orderDetailsArray;
}
```

If `orderDetailsArray` is not already a `string[]` you should copy it into one before you return it.

Comment: I just had to change public Array GetOrderDetailsArray() to public string[] GetOrderDetailArray() like you said.  Thanks!